# When should we choose other IPC instead of direct memory access for inter-thread communication

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, networking, ipc

Since threads in the same process share the same address space, we can transfer data among these threads through direct memory access and mutexes, then in this context I have below questions:

1. Are global variables and mutexes all enough for inter-thread communication?
2. if it's false for QUESTION 1, in what context should we choose other IPC instead of direct memory access? Or let's say, in what context other IPC means is more suitable than using global variables and mutexes?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Thanks @ssyam for pointing out the incorrect statement about "global variables".
I choose to add one more section other than correct the original paragraph because
many comments have been given on the paragraph.

Comment: As a side note (just nitpicking here...) IPC means "**inter** process communication" so it can't apply to threads (**in**-process communication). But we all got your meaning anyway. :)

Comment: @syam A nit about your nit.  The term interprocess communication preceded threads but I have never heard anyone balk at the term when applied to intra-process communication.  In linux, at least, there is not a whole lot of difference between a process and a thread anyway.

Comment: @Duck Actually you're right. Looking at the Wikipedia (I know...) definition, it seems that the term "IPC" is also used for inter-thread communications (even though it expands to "inter-process..."). I guess my OCD was acting up again, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, global variables are bad in single threaded code and in multi-threaded code they generally become a major problem. Even when synchronization is done properly with mutexes, they tend to become a bottleneck. Also, mutexes are generally not sufficient for inter-thread communication. You typically need, at least, also condition variables.

That said, within multi-threaded applications it is reasonable to transfer data between threads in memory. Generally, I found it not to be viable to deal with explicit locking, however. The code tends to be less complicated and more efficient when transferring the data similar to a message passing system, even if the messages are data structures in memory. In that sense, a message is at any time only used by one thread and the only locking happening is implicit in the message passing facilities.

Comment: I have been confused about this for long time. We have a multithreaded application with around 100 threads within it, and all threads use direct shared memory access other than message passing (here message passing I mean the way we do for inter-process communication). I found the code becomes ugly, and there are mutexes everywhere.

Comment: The question is where is the boundary of determing when to use direct memroy access with mutexes and conditions variable and when to use the message passing way instead. When should I choose the message passing other than the simple and conventional direct memory access?

Comment: @StevePeng Message passing is just another form of direct memory access. It usually involves a queue storing messages, and this queue is controlled by a mutex/condition_variable pair. But in the end, you still directly access the process' memory without using any system facility but the synchronization ones. I'm opposing that to using sockets, shared memory facilities (mmap) or other things that involve a lot of indirections through the kernel. Hope I am making myself clear. :)

Comment: @StevePeng: I'm always using message passing via in-process queues to transfer information between threads! Basically, the system passes around tasks having individual threads make process on a given task rather than trying to orchestrate many objects. The only places using mutexes and condition variables are the communication primitives, e.g., the queues used to transfer messages (and our internal version of that stuff also nicely deals with thread-pooling). The basic idea is called [Actor Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model).

Comment: @syam thanks, I know there must be some similar access-protect mechanism inside the system, but just as what pointed by Dietmar Kühl, " a message is at any time only used by one thread and the only locking happening is implicit in the message passing facilities", so the user-code can become less complicated (and more efficient if there are hundreds of threads accessing same bunch of different types of resources? I am not sure about this).

Comment: @DietmarKühl Funny, I didn't know about that "actor model", I always called it "producer/consumer" (... of messages). But in the end we're referring to the same stuff anyway. I have learned something again. :)

Comment: @StevePeng Yeah that's the whole point of message-passing communications: you try to design it so that each message is self-sufficient and doesn't reference any shared state. This way you need very little synchronization outside of the message queues themselves, which simplifies a lot the system. Less synchronization = less room for human errors.

Comment: @syam: Well, what I described isn't exactly the actor model (as that typically involves serialization of the messages, i.e., there are really values transferred) but it is similar. ... and the same idea goes under many names and variations. I don't like producer/consumer because most actors actually happen to be both but it is basically the same idea.

Comment: If you can possibly get away with a message-passing model, where no data is ever operated on by more than one thread, your should definitely do it.

Answer (score 1):

No need for **global** variables. Remember that thread routines can take parameters, so it might be *any* kind of variable, including dynamically allocated ones.

Usually you'll want to "wrap" your thread inside a class, something along the lines of:

```
struct Thread
{
    Thread() : m_thread(&Thread::run, this) {}
    void run()
    {
        // access the current object's member variables, eg:
        do_something_with(m_myvar);
    }

    Object m_myvar;
    std::thread m_thread;
};
```

But if we set aside this little detail of global variables, your #1 is right... Communicating through variables (be it message queues, booleans, whatever) protected by a mutex and optionally a `condition_variable` (to act as a wake-up trigger) is almost always the way to go.

I for one almost always end up using thread-safe message queues (ie. `std::queue + mutex + condition_variable`) to communicate between threads (producer/consumer pattern), it's a very efficient way to both isolate threads and allow them to communicate.

---

In fact, there are very few cases where something else than direct memory access would make sense inside a single process.

All I can think of right now is, if you already have some working inter-process code (eg. sockets or shared memory), you could reuse this code in order to allow for a uniform interface be it in-process or inter-process communications. But don't kid yourself, it *will* be less efficient as direct memory access. However, the benefits of a uniform interface can easily overcome the loss of efficiency. IMHO you really need to deal with this kind of stuff on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 1):

On (1) I agree with Dietmar Kühl that condition variables are part of that minimum set.

On (2) I tend to choose IPC whenever I can afford the small cost of the overhead (mostly a system call and some data copying) for the ease and flexibility that comes with them.  A pipe, a message queue, a domain socket, etc., all come with atomicity and synchronization built in and they offer blocking, non-blocking, or timed read/writes depending on what the situation requires.  And you can stuff them into a `select` statement without doing anything special.  It's a lot of power for a small cost and doesn't involved reinventing the wheel.

Comment: ..and are mind-blowingly inefficent for transferring large data buffers between process-local threads.

Comment: @Martin James - just pass pointers to the buffers, they are all in the same process.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thought:

Even though two threads are accessing the same memory does not necessarily mean that they see the same values. If one thread is updating the value the other one can see the stale value - the value before the update taken from the processor local cache. To prevent this from happening you need to synchronize the thread using mutexes or some other techniques.

Regardless of the technique, the local cache has to be flushed using what is called 'memory barrier' which is a pretty expensive operation because it will require all processors to stop whatever they are doing and wait for the operation to complete.

The IPC call on the other hand does not necessarily require that.

Comment: 'The IPC call on the other hand does not necessarily require that' - really?